# How to query firebase on the last (x,y)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-queue

I am listing an array based on the votes (`orderByChild('up')`) and like to divide them into pages (`limitToLast(10*formData.page)`). However, `limitToLast()` only takes one attribute rather then two, so for example if I am the page 10, I would have a huge list of items...

```
ref.orderByChild('up').limitToLast(10*formData.page).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var data = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    data.unshift(child.val());
  });
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
  response.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  response.end();
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log('Database reading error: ' + errorObject.code);
  response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.write('Database reading error: ' + errorObject.code);
  response.end();
});
```

Of course I can use a function similar to this one:

```
function reversedChildren(snapshot) {
    var children = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) { children.unshift(child); });
    return children;
}
```

But this method seems to require getting the entire list first and then use snapshot.forEach to reverse the list before turning them into a list. Let's say if the list is 4GB, it means it will need to load 4GB of data to just show 10 entries...

Comment: are you trying to paginate?

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu yes, check my update

Comment: could you kindly post some snippet of the current code and and an expected output? It will help me get to a solution as per your requirements... the answer that was posted was only an example to fetch data between two specific indexes...